# Unbounded knapsack pseducode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I need to modify wiki's knapsack pseudocode for my homework so it checks whether you can achieve exact weight W in the knapsack or not. Number of items is unlimited and you the value not important. I am thinking to add a while loop under j>-W[j] to check how many same items would it fit. Will that work?

Thanks

```
// Input:
// Values (stored in array v)
// Weights (stored in array w)
// Number of distinct items (n)
// Knapsack capacity (W)
for w from 0 to W do
  m[0, w] := 0
end for 
for i from 1 to n do
  for j from 0 to W do
    if j >= w[i] then
      m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
    else
      m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
    end if
  end for
end for
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not missing anything, if you are referring to [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

In the modified version, your `values` array shall be the same as your `w` array. After calculating `m[n,W]`, simply check whether it is equal to `W`.

EDIT:
If you have unlimited number of items, then you are dealing with **Unbounded Knapsack Problem**. This is a different problem and the same article gives the dynamic programming implementation for solving it.

Comment: Yes, that article. So how to account for unlimited items? Would my idea of adding a while loop work?

Comment: Yeah I saw it but my formal english is pretty bad and I am not getting what the article wants me to do. Would greatly appreciate some elaboration